# Parent Join in elasticsearch is not searching as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-7

We recently migrated from the elastic search version 5.5 to 7.7
The elastic search version 7.7 has removed the concept of the multiple types, so we used the **JOIN** data type for mapping the relationship between **users** and **tweets** like below

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html

```
PUT twitter
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "my_join_field": { 
        "type": "join",
        "relations": {
          "users": "tweets" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so where the **users** is the **parent** and **tweets** are the children
My twitter index has 1 million entries in the combination of users and tweets, 
It works as expected when I use hasParentQuery / hasChildQuery, I get the proper result.

But when I try to query only the parent in the twitter index (i.e) In this case, I want to search only on **users** in the twitter index, I query like below

```
    // to filter only users 
    QueryBuilder query1 = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("my_join_field", "users"); 
    // to get all the users whose name starts with joh...   
    QueryBuilder query2 = QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("username", "*joh*").boost(1.0f); 
    BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(resourceQuery).must(wildcard);

    SearchResponse searResp = commondao.prepareSearch("twitter").setQuery(boolQueryBuilder).setFrom(from).setSize(size).execute().actionGet();
```

the twitter index has 1 million records with 50K entries of users and remaining as tweets. 
This query is taking the same time (**with / without passing the my_join_field as users**) as searching the whole index.

What I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!